# Not getting desired results by using javascript startsWith(), why?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to implement a search widget in HTML by using java-script; which uses a text box and a select control; and searches contents of an XML file for the typed content.
To compare the string entered by user dynamically with XML file content I am using a function which I call at every key up event of the text box in search widget.
But even though I use the 'starts with' function in java-script to compare the string and XML content I am unable to get the desired results. What could be the issue?
The code is here:

```
function addMedicineNames(){
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var file = "medicines.xml";
            rawFile.open("GET",file,false);
            var allXml;
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    {
                        allXml = rawFile.responseXML;

                    }
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
            var nodes = allXml.getElementsByTagName("medicinename");
            for(var nodeIndex=0; nodeIndex<nodes.length; nodeIndex++){
                var option = document.createElement("option"); 
                var medname = document.getElementById("medtextbox").value.toString();
                var nodename = nodes[nodeIndex].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toString();
                if(nodename.startsWith(medname)){
                    alert("true");
                }else{
                    alert("false");
                }                  
            }            
        }
```

The XML file content is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <medicinename>
           Sulpitac 50mg
   </medicinename>
   <medicinename>
          Sulpitac 20mg
   </medicinename>
</root>
```

Adding a screenshot:
[The alert shows false but it should be true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1s4z.jpg)

Comment: Please add what result are you getting from this code.

Comment: What browser are you using? Not all browsers fully support it.  Also have you tried trimming the whitespace from the start of the node value

Comment: @Pete Thank you the white spaces was the issue.